# What is the best strategy to survive in water?

Tags: swimming

Imagine, you are shipwrecked in a warm lake (drinkable water) with 25°C water temperature and without lifeboat or anything, plain naked.
You have to wait to be rescued and have to pace yourself. So you have to decide about how you keep yourself on the water:

- swim breast stroke
- swim backstroke
- just drift on the back

What kind of swimming technique would let you last the longest?

Comment: Are you trying to get to shore or just swim the longest duration?

Comment: Refer http://outdoors.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask. "you are asking an open-ended, hypothetical question: “What if ______ happened?”

Comment: The proven answer is [Drown Proofing.](http://www.drownproofing.com/)

Comment: This doesn't seem open ended, shemSeger should write the comment as answer. Exactly what i was looking for.

Comment: @rubo77 I've already provided that answer for a significantly similar question, hence why I voted to mark this question as duplicate.